# SPARQL query for and create

Tags: mapping, sparql, owl, bpmn

I have a mapping of two ontologies.  I'm trying to create some individuals in our class Sequence flow in BPMN.  The following pseudo-code describes the process;  how can I do this in SPARQL?

```
int numbergateways;
Count(gateways) as numberGateways
For (int i=0; i< numberGatewas; i++)
  String CreateSequenceflow =””;
  CreateSequenceflow with the name of the Gateway + “to” \
              + ”the name of the 2 next tasks connecting with the gateway”
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? And it would be easier when you show (parts) of the data resp. schema.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. I uploaded all of my classes. Im using Protege to work with this files. : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=33285382023709831025

Comment: Short summary, i am writing my master thesis. I have an basic example, a Trip.  I need to map from BPMn to YAWL and backwards. I created my own YAWL Ontology based on an XSD file. The concpept of sequence flow is a bit different in both concepts, so i came up with this solution Im new to SPARQL so had my diffuculties to translate this Pseudo Code to SPARQL. Not sure you can solve this problem via axioms. Thanks in advance!

Comment: forgot to mention you need to open the mapping file(main file). Other files need to be imported. Help would be really appreciated!!! Need a for loop and a create statement

Comment: @Joshua Taylor, do you need any further information or you cant help me at all? So i will look for another solution thank you :)